# Choosing database for the app that target windows phone7 and windows phone8 OS?

Tags: sql, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have to develop and enterprise app that should work in both windows phone 7 and 8(app targeting to older and latest OS). This is an app porting from android to windows phone. 
The proposed app has lots of database interactions like order processing and payments(bulk CRUD operation should be handled) in both offline and online mode.
Also, at the time of login , the app should check for the DB change in the server and need to make the corresponding changes in the local phone app database accordingly either by downloading the SqlLite file or any otherway from the server.

I heard that, Windows phone supports following approaches to deal with database interactions;

- LINQ to SQL Data Context(WP7)
- SQLLite(WP8)
- SQL CE(WP7.5)
- SterlingDB

And i would like to design the database/table using an IDE like SQLLite manager or sql server ,for easy of db design.

My Question is: which DB approach is good for my app to achieve the following requirements?

1. App target the OS WP7 and WP8.
2. DB design support(IDE to add/modify the DB or tables)
3. offline data Sync
4. LINQ Support.
5. DB changes in server need to be get updated in the local app(by downloading .sdf/.sql kinda file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the SQLite C# Community port on both WP7 and WP8. I think it is a little out of date now - and doesn't seem to me actively maintained - but it has worked well for me. See http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/ for more info.

You can also use the native SQLite library on WP8 - and this is the officially recommended WP8 solution and is maintained - but I've found this requires more project level setup.

For LINQ support, I personally use SQLite-net - https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/ - but other solutions are available - e.g.  Vici CoolStorage - http://viciproject.com/

For offline data sync and for sdf updates, I've not seen any automated solutions - I believe you may have to code this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So which DB approach should i choose if we target only for windows phone 8. LINQ to SQL(Code first) or SQLite?

Comment: i have found some old articles to deal with sqllite in windowsphone8; Author's opinion was its just a workaround to start with Sqllite in windowsphone8 and there is some research work is being happening in sqllite for windowsphone8. Is there any new library or methodology released recently?  could anyone suggest me straight solution rather than a workaround ??

Comment: @sherifm2d Check this blog post http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/05/30/sqlite-winrt-wrapper-for-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: @nkchadra thank you so much for sharing the latest updates.I will check the same and update it here.